Getting JSON_PARSER_ERROR on salesforce production during post call(Rest API)
I am getting "message=Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields." and "statusCode=JSON_PARSER_ERROR" on Salesforce production Rest api. What can be done correct this?
Method: Post
Request:
    {
  "records": [
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2024-10-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2024-11-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2024-12-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-01-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-02-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-03-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-04-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-05-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-06-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-07-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-08-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "type": "OpportunityLineItemSchedule",
      "Type": "Revenue",
      "Description": "",
      "OpportunityLineItemId": "00kNr000008KmjpIAC",
      "Revenue": "-5.4",
      "ScheduleDate": "2025-09-18T05:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}

Response:
   [
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "success":false,
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR",
            "message":"Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.",
            "fields":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]


I have changed type to Revenue and still getting the same error. Do I need to add any other value?
